# Animating an image using Titanium for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have an image bell. I want this to be animated such that it from right-to- left and left-to-right indefinitely. I tried with the following coding but I'm unable to achieve it:

```
var curWin = Ti.UI.createWindow;
var nButto = Ti.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage : "/images/bell.png",
    height : 29,
    width : 29,
    top : 0,
    enabled : false,
    textAlign : Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT,
    font : {
        fontFamily : 'OpenSans-Regular',
        fontSize : 17
    }
});
curWin.add(nButto);
var matrix = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
matrix = matrix.rotate(90);
var a = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    transform : matrix,
    duration : 500,
    autoreverse : true,
    repeat : 0,
    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT ,
});


var matrix1 = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
matrix1 = matrix.rotate(180);
var a1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    transform : matrix1,
    duration : 500,
    autoreverse : true,
    repeat : 0,
    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT ,
});

nButto.animate(a);
nButto.animate(a1);

nButto.anchorPoint = {
    x : 0.5,
    y : 0.5
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an eventListener to both animation, call animation 2 in the complete listener of 1 and 1 in the listener of 2.

```
a.addEventListener('complete',function(e){
  //your code for callback function here.
});
```